# Problem with reading GPIO input value - photoeletric sensor

Tags: pi-3, python-3, input-device, signal

Good night!

I've got some problems with GPIO input values in my code (Python). I'm using a Raspberry Pi model 3, and RPi.GPIO as GPIO module. I'm tring to get the signal values of a photoeletric sensor and there's some problems when the code tries to get this information. I assambled a system whit a motor, a little wheel with holes (It gets each time the wheel turn a round), and the sensor. I tried to use a very low rotation of motor, to ensure the problem is not (only) the velocity. As shown in the figure, each time the wheel hole pass trought the photoeletric sensor, the input signal value is zero (0); otherwise, the signal is one (1). But, as shown in the graph, there are some falts (as though the code is not correctly processing the input values). I'd like to get every single input signal, to measure as fine as possible the input value.

The photoeletric sensor is running ok, I test in oscilloscope. When I look at the sensor, when the wheel hole pass through the sensor, a green led blinks, no matter the velocity. So, as I think, the problem is not in the physical configuration. This sensor has no identification (I just bought it as "Encoder Sensor"). In the picture below, all the holes are exposed (in the actual configuration I just kept two holes exposed, to ensure all that the problem is not the precision of the sensor, but it's ok in any way).

For the wires, I connected directly the Digital output of the sensor in the GPIO19. The 5 Vcc and GND normally.

I'm using a DC motor, with 380 rpm of max speed. To control the motor, I used a H bridge (L298N), and set up a PWM duty cycle of 30% (shown in the code).

Here is the code I'm using; I got it from https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/graph-sensor-data-with-python-and-matplotlib/speeding-up-the-plot-animation and edit it for my purpouse.

Thank's for all the tags and advices!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


x_len = 200         # Number of points to display
y_range = [-2, 4]  # Range of possible Y values to display


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = list(range(0, 200))
ys = [0] * x_len
ax.set_ylim(y_range)

in1 = 24
in2 = 23
encoder = 19
enable = 25


GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(in1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(enable,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(encoder,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 

vel = GPIO.PWM(enable,1000)
vel.start(30)

GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)

line, = ax.plot(xs, ys)


plt.title('GPIO Signal')
plt.xlabel('Sample')
plt.ylabel('Signal Value')


def animate(i, ys):

    valor = GPIO.input(encoder)

    # Add y to list
    ys.append(valor)

    #Limit y list to set number of items
    ys = ys[-x_len:]

   #Update line with new Y values
    line.set_ydata(ys)

    return line,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
    animate,
    fargs=(ys,),
    interval=0,
    blit=True)

GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)


plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide some more information about your setup and project. Can you edit the post and add the code that you are using? What is the photoelectric sensor that you are using? Can you observe the fault happening in real time - that is you see the sensor showing up thru the hole, but it doesn't register the input signal? Is the pattern deterministic (it always misses specific holes or at a specific time interval) or does it seem random?

Comment: DC motor or stepping motor? Which motor driver? What speed?

Comment: Need the code.  You are probably better off using the pigpio Python module.

Comment: Suggestion: Reduce the code. Don't worry about the motor code, remove the motor and turn your wheel by hand.